# Gluon Mobile arm android support

Tags: gluon, gluon-mobile

I already know from the [documentation](https://docs.gluonhq.com/#_getting_started) that GluonMobile currently does not provide native images support for android on arm architectures, but only AArch64.

Does anybody know any workaround to have your application run on android (arm) with GluonMobile?

That said, since there is arm support for iOS, is there any chance that such a feature is going to be provided for android in the near future?

Comment: There is _arm64_ support for iOS, not _arm32_. Currently GraalVM doesn't support any 32-bits platform, only 64 bits (x86_64/arm64/aarch64).

Comment: @JoséPereda Thanks a lot for the quick clarification. I really appreciate all the effort that you guys at Gluon put in this tool.